# Cordova browser app doesn't recognize cordova.plugins.backgroundMode

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm making a cordova app and I included the background mode plugin, then i used the line cordova.plugins.backgroundMode according to the official documentation and the app doesn't recognize it. Yes I've included cordova.js before app.js, yes I'm sure the plugin is properly installed since it didn't give any error message while installing it, it appears in the plugin list and I reinstalled it with multiple versions and not a single one works. One thing I found weird is that npm didn't add this plugin to config.xml. Can anyone help with this?

I tried reinstalling the plugin, tried just calling backgroundMode, tried using it on an android phone but it doesn't work.

Comment: which target-sdk version do you use? It seems to not be working anymore with target-sdk 31, according to this issue https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/574 There also appear to be issues with cordova-anrdroid-10: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/567

Comment: and just to check, this is the one you're using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-mode? There seem to be a few ones, including the words: "fixed, advanced and android", implying that it didn't work anymore for some people, you could try those

Comment: @Mister_CK how do I check the target-sdk version? I use gradle 26 if that could help, and yes I'm using that version of the plugin.

Comment: the highest gradle release is: 7.6 b(from last november): https://gradle.org/releases/ so I doubt that your using 26 :P targets-sdk should be a preference in your config.xml inside the android tag, like this:  
   `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26" />
                 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />`

Comment: If you don't have a target-sdk specified I think you use the default for a cordova-android version. So which cordova-android version do you use? (10 uses 30, 11 uses 32)